# didSelectRowAtIndexPath changes indexPath value every time I press the same row?

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath, nsindexpath

I was trying to change value if user push same table cell again and again.

In my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, I create indexPath with value from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` method but this value changes every time I press the same table cell.

Is it normal?

My goal is when user push some table cell create NSObject with two properties (nameOfItem, numberOfItem). numberOfItem is default set to 1. I want to change this number +1 every time he push the same table cell.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString*nameForItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.ivc.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    Items *item = [Items new];
    [item setNameOfItem:nameForItem];
    [item setNumberOfItem:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

    if (indexPath == self.index) {
        [item setNumberOfItem:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[item.numberOfItem integerValue]+1]]; 
    }

    self.index = indexPath;
```

Comment: **1.** can you, please clarify how you meant _this value changes every time I press the same table cell_? **2.** what do you expect from this comparison: `if (indexPath == self.index) { ... }`, regarding the same instance of `indexPath` can hold different `row` and `section` values? **3.** are you aware of this line `self.index = [NSIndexPath new];` is totally pointless here?

Comment: thank you for info. I am new in programming :) please check my edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about your real problem, and the goal what you'd like to achieve here... but I would improve your code-snippet like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString*nameForItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.ivc.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    Items *item = [Items new];
    [item setNameOfItem:nameForItem];
    [item setNumberOfItem:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

    // improving comparison
    if (indexPath.row == self.index.row && indexPath.section == self.index.section) {
        [item setNumberOfItem:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[item.numberOfItem integerValue]+1]]; 
    }

    // removing unnecessary instantiate and deep-copying the current index path
    self.index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];
}
```

---

#### issue #1

while you comparing the actual pointers like:

```
if (indexPath == self.index) { ... }
```

you need to know the *same* instance of `NSIndexSet` can hold different `row` and `section` values (as per in my comment) as they are reused(!) by the `UITableView`, so you probably want to compare the actual indices rather than the pointers.

---

#### issue #2

while you retain the pointer for the index path like:

```
self.index = indexPath;
```

you need to be aware of the exact same thing I've mentioned one paragraph above, about the same instance of `NSIndexPath` can be and *will be* reused to present new indices.

---

## update

if you wish to handle a counter for each index path (=rows in the current instance of the `UITableView`), you need to store those number somewhere permanently, in some collection.

I'm not sure about the current environment, so I'm trying to present a generic solution for the problem.

in your class you will need this (private) collection:

```
NSMutableDictionary *_counters;
```

and I would change your method like this, regarding I don't know what `Items` is, I chucked everything away entirely, that is I have currently:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (_counters == nil) _counters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSString *_key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03ld:%03ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
    NSInteger _currentCounterForIndexPath = [[_counters objectForKey:_key] integerValue];
    [_counters setObject:@(++_currentCounterForIndexPath) forKey:_key];
}
```

this will count the taps on each row for you, and increases the number of the taps every time for each row.

the `_counter` dictionary will have the details like this (logged at a random stage of my test app):

```
_counter : {
    "000:000" = 5;
    "000:001" = 1;
    "000:003" = 2;
    "000:004" = 6;
    "000:005" = 3;
    "000:006" = 1;
}
```

where the `AAA:BBB` is the *key* from the current `section` (`AAA`) and the current `row` (`BBB`), and the *value* is the number of taps.

so, you can read that collection as

- in section 0 the row 0 was tapped `5` times;
- in section 0 the row 1 was tapped `1` times;
- in section 0 the row 2 was tapped `0` times; **(there is no record about any tap for this row!)**
- in section 0 the row 3 was tapped `2` times;
- in section 0 the row 4 was tapped `6` times;
- in section 0 the row 5 was tapped `3` times;
- in section 0 the row 6 was tapped `1` times;

---

later if you are curious to get the number of taps for a particular `row` in a particular `section`, you can reuse the code from my updated method, like e.g. for section 0, row 5:

```
NSString *_key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03ld:%03ld", 0, 5];
NSInteger _currentCounterForIndexPath = [[_counters objectForKey:_key] integerValue];
```

the `_currentCounterForIndexPath` will have the number of taps, which is `3` currently.

I guess that is such simple.

Comment: Very well explained :) please check my edit above to know what is my goal.

Comment: @M.Koptak, I've updated my answer, hopefully that is what you have been looking for.

Comment: It is exactly what i was looking for! Many thanks to you. Wish for more peoples here like you are :) And sorry for my english btw.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing objects with each other here:

```
if (indexPath == self.index)
```

What you want to do is compare the content of the two indexPaths (which should be the same, in your case):

```
if ([indexPath isEqual:self.index]) ...
```

or

```
if ([indexPath compare:self.index] == NSOrderedSame) ...
```

Comment: what is this solution for, exactly? that is far away from any usable solution for the OP's original – and updated – question.